# Socket.emit prints <span> tags in a formatted message

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I'm currently trying to create a tiny chat app on `Node.js`, `Express.js`, and `Socket.IO`, but I'm having an issue with formatting it: for some reason, instead of actually using the `<span>` tags in the formatted message, it prints them to the chat.

I tried to format it in various ways, create some other functions to do it, nothing worked so far.

Why may that be?

```
server.js

  socket.on('message', (message) => {
    const timestamp = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { hour12: false, hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });
    const usernameSpan = `<span class="chat-user">${users[socket.id]}</span>`;
    const messageSpan = `<span class="chat-message">${message}</span>`;
    const timeSpan = `<span class="chat-time">[${timestamp}]</span>`;
    const formattedMessage = `${timeSpan} ${usernameSpan}: ${messageSpan}`;

    if (message.startsWith('/')) {
      const [command, ...args] = message.split(' ');
      switch (command) {
        // commands go here
      }
    } else {
      messages.push(formattedMessage);
      if (messages.length > MAX_MESSAGES) { // if >500 messages already stored
        messages.shift();
      }
      io.emit('message', formattedMessage);
      console.log(`${users[socket.id]}: ${message}`);
      fs.appendFile('recent-messages.txt', `${formattedMessage}\n`, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
      });
    }
  }); 


client.js

messageForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const message = messageInput.value;
    if (message) {
        socket.emit('message', message);
        messageInput.value = '';
        checkForSpam();
    }
});

socket.on('message', (message) => {
    const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
    messageElement.setAttribute('class', 'message');
    messageElement.textContent = message;
    messagesDiv.appendChild(messageElement);
    chatBoxDiv.scrollTop = chatBoxDiv.scrollHeight;
    checkForSpam();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, had to swap out `messageElement.textContent = message;` for `messageElement.innerHTML = formattedMessage;`, also added another function for formatting messages, based on a RegEx.